# Filtering a SharePoint list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, custom-list, filter

I have 2 lists and 2 pages.

The first one lets call it System contains 2 columns, Name and Action.  The Action column is a URL that redirects to the second page.

The second one lets call it Subsystem contains 2 columns as well, System (lookup from the System list, specifically the Name column).

Each of this list is in a displayed in a page.  So the first list is displayed in page1.aspx and when a user clicks on a URL under the Action column, it redirects to page2.aspx which filters the Subsystem list belonging to the System.  Here's a sample URL:
        http://server01.com/SitePages/page1.aspx#InplviewHashAE5AEDA2-1493-412A-ACD6-CCDF4B7E8F1F=CascDelWarnMessage%3D1-FilterField1%3DSystem-FilterValue1%3Dtest

Now my problem is when the second page is loaded, the table first displays all the items before filtering it.  Is there any way to hide this "flickering" thing from the users?

I would really appreciate any help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the second page use two filters separated by OR condition.

1. Id = 0
2. Query string filter

Now Id = 0 will not return any values by default. When query string is present, the view works as exi.

Comment: Hi Amal, thanks for the suggestion. I added a filter of ID=0 in the default view but when the URL was loaded, it still displayed 0 results.  May I know how you were able to achieve this?

Comment: Make Sure the conditions are `OR` in the filter settings.

Comment: Hi Amal, you mean in the list's view settings right?  In the ViewEdit.aspx under the Filter part.  It doesn't work for me.